# Python - storing large arrays in variables

Tags: python, dataframe, variables, fits

I have a dataframe which is storing (or trying to) 5 fields of arrays 1489*2048 image files and a classification.  I have tried json and other formats, and am currently using Pandy Data Frames.  When i process the files to extract the image arrays and put them into the data frame i get truncated data....
the initial data is FITS files and i am taking the HUD0 data for astro images across 5 bands to put into an array so i can do some machine learning on it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#from array import *
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.visualization import astropy_mpl_style
plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)
import os
os.chdir('d:\\project\\masters')


# table of definitations for classification
# 1 is a star
# 2 is a galaxy
# 3 is a quazar

classification = 1

with open('input.txt') as f:
    i=0
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()
        band_u = fits.open(line, memmap=True)

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()
        band_g = fits.open(line, memmap=True)

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()
        band_r = fits.open(line, memmap=True)

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()
        band_i = fits.open(line, memmap=True)

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip() 
        band_z = fits.open(line, memmap=True)     

        data1 = band_u[0].data
        data2 = band_g[0].data
        data3 = band_r[0].data
        data4 = band_i[0].data 
        data5 = band_z[0].data
        #
        #
        #
        my_array = np.array([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, classification])
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_array)
        df.to_csv(r'pandas.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
        # np.save('data.npy' , my_array)
        print(i)
        i += 1 # to track progress
    f.close()
```

output example

```
**"[[-0.0244751   0.01791382 -0.00328064 ... -0.01081848  0.06750488
   0.01052856]
 [-0.01739502  0.01791382 -0.01739502 ... -0.02505493  0.01763916
  -0.00370789]
 [-0.03155518 -0.0244751  -0.01739502 ...  0.07458496 -0.01081848
   0.01052856]**
```

need to get rid of the truncation....any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a display issue or did you open the file in an editor and thats the full extend of the files content?

Comment: the data1-5 variables are listed as Array's of float32 and 1489,2048 in size.  I have done a data1.size and get 3,049,472 back - so they are correct but the variable window shows truncated values - which is ok.....however the output above is from a text file and that is also truncated.  i am writing the data variables and a classification value into another dataframe and outputting that......which is the example of output above.

Comment: so the desired output is a dataframe with 5 df's of 3049472 and 1 of 1 for classification.  if i am going about this all wrong then won't be offended by being guided in the right direction

Comment: How was your "output example" produced? None of the code you posted prints anything except the progress index `i` (by the way, if you want to track progress, [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a very nice and easy to use progress bar). I think what @PatrickArtner is asking is, is this what the actual CSV file looks like?

Comment: df.to_csv(r'pandas.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')

Comment: this is a copy past of the test file output:   "[[-0.0244751   0.01791382 -0.00328064 ... -0.01081848  0.06750488
   0.01052856]
 [-0.01739502  0.01791382 -0.01739502 ... -0.02505493  0.01763916
  -0.00370789]
 [-0.03155518 -0.0244751  -0.01739502 ...  0.07458496 -0.01081848
   0.01052856]
 ...
 [-0.01705933  0.00413513 -0.02410889 ... -0.0033493  -0.00335312
  -0.00335312]
"[[-0.0244751   0.01791382 -0.00328064 ... -0.01081848  0.06750488
   0.01052856]
 [-0.01739502  0.01791382 -0.01739502 ... -0.02505493  0.01763916

Comment: Hang in there, I'm working on an answer.  I see your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might see your problem.  Each of your band data is already a Numpy array, but `classification` is just a single integer.  But here you do:

```
my_array = np.array([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, classification])
```

This creates a Numpy "array" of mixed data types: arrays and an integer.  This results in an array of type "object" (Numpy arrays are supposed to be homogeneous in the data types of the items, but if you try to create one from a heterogeneous list you will just get an "object" array.  To illustrate the difference, if you pass a list of equally sized arrays to `np.array()` it will stack them into a 2D array:

```
>>> np.array([np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(10)])                                    
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

But if you add a single `int` to the end of this list it will produce an array of dtype `object` (because the input is mixed data types that don't have an "obvious" conversion between them):

```
>>> a2 = np.array([np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(10), 1])                            
>>> a2                                                                                         
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 1], dtype=object)
>>> a2.dtype                                                                                   
dtype('O')
```

When you then try to instantiate a pandas `DataFrame` from this, it doesn't really know what to do with it.  Or at least, it doesn't do with it what you want--it just creates a `DataFrame` with a single column of type "object" ("object" here meaning generic Python objects that are not necessarily homogeneous in type):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a2)                                                                      
>>> df                                                                                         
                                0
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3                               1
>>> df.dtypes                                                                                  
0    object
dtype: object
```

I think what you wanted to do was to construct a `DataFrame` with one column per band and a classification column.  To do this, there is no reason to pass your existing arrays to `np.array()` as in the line I highlighted.  You can just pass a list of columns to `pd.DataFrame()`.  In this case you should also fill the initial classification out to an array of the same length of the other arrays.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((band_r, band_g, np.full(band_r.shape, classification))))
```

You can also make a `DataFrame` with named columns like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'band_r': band_r, 'band_g': band_g,
                   'classification': np.full(band_r.shape, classification)})
```

For what it's worth, here's one way I might write your code.  I generalized it so it can work with any number of bands--instead of reading them as a simple list of filenames you can read in a JSON file mapping the band names to filenames they're read from.  Of course, for your application this might be overkill.  This is untested:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

def bands_to_dataframe(bands, initial_classification=1):
    """bands is a dict mapping band names to filenames"""

    columns = {}

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        for band_name, filename in bands.items():
            hdulist = stack.enter_context(fits.open(filename))
            columns[band_name] = hdulist[0].data

        # use the shape of the first band data array to determine the
        # correct shape of the classification column; this assumes all
        # the arrays are the same size
        first_band = next(iter(columns.values())
        columns['classification'] = np.full(first_band.shape, initial_classification)

        return pd.DataFrame(columns)
```

Tying it all together, given a JSON file like:

```
{
    "band_r": "path/to/band_r.fits",
    "band_g": "path/to/band_g.fits",
    "band_i": "path/to/band_i.fits",
    ... and so on ...
}
```

You can do:

```
def band_files_to_csv(bands_filename, output_filename=None):
    """Read band filenames from a JSON file structured as above and
    write their data to a TSV file.
    """

    if output_filename is None:
        base_filename, _ = os.path.splitext(bands_filename)
        output_filename = base_filename + '.tsv'

    with open(bands_filename) as fobj:
        bands = json.load(fobj)

    df = bands_to_dataframe(bands)
    df.to_csv(output_filename, header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

Something like that.  I'm not exactly sure why you want to save this data to CSV/TSV; depending on what your application is it might not be the most efficient format (e.g. you might want to consider a binary format).  But whatever works for your application.

**Update:** If you are always working with the same sequence of bands `(u, g, r, i, z)` and you just want to read a list of files without resorting to JSON you could also do something like this (mostly the same):

```
DEFAULT_BANDS = ('u', 'g', 'r', 'i', 'z')


def bands_to_dataframe(bands, band_names=DEFAULT_BANDS,
                       initial_classification=1):
    """bands is a list of filenames"""

    if len(bands) != len(band_names):
        raise ValueError(
           f'number of filenames ({len(bands)}) does not match the '
           f'number of band names: {band_names}')

    columns = {}

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        for band_name, filename in zip(band_names, bands):
            hdulist = stack.enter_context(fits.open(filename))
            columns['band_' + band_name] = hdulist[0].data

        # ... the rest is the same as previous version ...
```

Then

```
from contextlib import nullcontext


def bands_file_to_csv(filename_or_obj, band_names=DEFAULT_BANDS,
                      output_filename_or_obj=None):
    """Here filename_or_obj can be a filename, or an already open
    file-like object."""

    if isinstance(filename_or_obj, (str, pathlib.Path)):
        input_file = open(filename_or_obj)
    else:
        input_file = nullcontext(filename_or_obj)

    if output_filename_or_obj is None:
        if isinstance(filename_or_obj, (str, pathlib.Path)):
            base_filename, _ = os.path.splitext(filename_or_obj)
            output_filename = base_filename + '.tsv'
            output_ctx = open(output_filename, 'a')
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                'output_filename_or_obj is required if input filename '
                'is not a string or path')
    else:
        if isinstance(output_filename_or_obj, (str, pathlib.Path)):
            output_ctx = open(output_filename_or_obj, 'a')
        else:
            output_ctx = nullcontext(output_filename_or_obj)

    # read all non-empty lines from the file
    # this uses the Python 3.8 walrus operator to avoid
    # calling l.strip() twice, but you could do this other
    # ways for older Python versions
    bands = [ll for l in input_file if (ll := l.strip())]

    df = bands_to_dataframe(bands, band_names=band_names)

    with output_ctx as output_file:
        df.to_csv(output_file, header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
```

Implementing this as a function without hard-coding the input filename is very useful.  It's more reusable, and it make for writing a better script (e.g. that takes the input filename as an argument).  You could also write a script that reads the list of filenames from standard input like:

```
# myscript.py
import sys
from contextlib import nullcontext

# output to stdout by default
output_file = sys.stdout

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    bands_file = sys.argv[1]
    ctx = open(bands_file)
    # If a second argument is provided it can be the output filename,
    # otherwise by default it outputs to stdout
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        output_file = open(sys.argv[2])
else:
    # If no filename is given as an argument, read from stdin
    # and output to stdout
    ctx = nullcontext(sys.stdin)

with ctx as input_file:
    bands_file_to_csv(input_file, output_filename_or_obj=output_file)
```

You can call this script in a few different ways.  Given an input filename:

```
$ ./myscript.py inputs.txt > bands.tsv
```

it will write its output to `bands.tsv` (without the `> bands.tsv` it will just write to the screen which you probably don't want for a huge file).

Or you can pass an output filename like:

```
$ ./myscript.py inputs.txt > bands.tsv
```

Finally, you can pass the inputs to stdin and output to a file:

```
$ cat inputs.txt | ./myscript.py > bands.tsv
```

This way you can build pipelines of scripts.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had tried json's previously but kept getting sterilization issues....and it is all back to the mismatch in types as you said.  Really appreciate both the input and the time / improvements you suggest.  My not wedded to any format of output as long as i can read it later into a CNN for training, but that is the least of my problems...I am going to work on your suggestion make it work for me.  thanks, will let you know how i get on.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're almost always working with the same sequence of bands and you just want to use a list of filenames like you were doing before, that could still work too.  I'm about to add an update that shows how you might approach that (while still keeping the code somewhat generalized).

Comment: Sorry, I think I went a bit overboard at the end.  Take what's useful to you and leave the rest :)